# Proof that the sum of two subspaces $A$ and $B$ when $A\cap B = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If 
$$A\cap B = \{0\}$$ and $A$ and $B$ are subspaces, then the sum of the subspaces is defined by

$$A+B = \{a+b |a\in A, b\in B\}$$

If their intersection is $\{0\}$ then its natural to think that $w$ in $A+B$ has na unique decomposition in terms of $A$ and $B$.

My book proves this by this argument:

$$w = u+v = u_1 + v_1\implies u-u_1 = v_1-v$$But $v_1-v\in V$, then $u-u_1\in U\cap V = \{0\}$. Then $u-u_1 = 0\implies u_1 = u$

Can somebody explain to me why

$$v_1-v\in V \implies u-u_1\in U\cap V = \{0\}$$?

After this, the book follows by proving the converse. He picks $w\in U\cap V$ and $u\in U$, $v\in V$. Then he writes the sum:

$$u+v = (u+w) + (v-w)$$

Then, by the unicity of the hypotesis, he says that

$u = u+w$ and $v = v-w$

Then $w = 0$, then $U\cap V = \{0\}$

Why the unicity implies $u = u+w$ and $v = v-w$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your textbook writes $w=u+v=u_1+v_1$ it (implicitly or explicitly) assumes that $u\in U$, $v\in V$, $u_1\in U$ and $v_1$. (I don't really understand why you change from $A$ and $B$ to $U$ and $V$, but it's not so relevant).

Since $U$ is a subspace, $u-u_1\in U$; similarly, $v_1-v\in V$. As $u-u_1=v_1-v$, this vector is in the intersection, so it's $0$.

The converse amounts to proving that

> if every vector $x\in U+V$ can be written in one and only one way as $x=u+v$, with $u\in U$ and $v\in V$, then $U\cap V=\{0\}$.

So, let $w\in U\cap V$; we wish to prove that $w=0$. Let $u\in U$ and $v\in V$; then set $x=u+v$. By simple algebra, we have also
$$
x=(u+w)+(v-w)
$$
and $u+w\in U$, $v-w\in V$. By assumption, there is *only one way* to write $x$ as sum of a vector in $U$ with a vector in $V$, but we have found two:
$$
x=u+v,\qquad x=(u+w)+(v-w)
$$
It follows that these ways are not different, so
$$
u=u+w\quad\text{and}v=v-w
$$
which means $w=0$.

Comment: But why $u = u+w$? I know that $w$ is both in $u$ and in the intersection, but this does not mean $w$ is null.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs $w$ is *any* element in $U\cap V$; so you prove that if you pick any $w\in U\cap V$, then $w=0$. Therefore $U\cap V=\{0\}$.

Comment: you said that $u+w \in U$ and $v-w \in V$. What I don't understand is how it leads to $w=0$

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs Because of the assumption on uniqueness of representation as sum of a vector in $U$ with one in $V$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand. Uniqueness implies exactly what? Could you please update it in your answer? I'll accept it anyway, but it would help me more.

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs I tried to explain it in full details.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is $v - v_1 \in V$, but also $u - u_1 \in U$ (by the same argument). Therefore $u-u_1 = v-v_1 \in U \cap V = \{0\}$.